# Synchronous wrapper for WCF asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous, synchronization

We are calling WCF services asyncronously.

```
public partial class ServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyService>, MyService 
{
    ......
}

ServiceClient _serviceclient;
void Getproducts(string filter, string augument, EventHandler<GetCompletedEventArgs> callback)
{
    _serviceclient.GetAsyncGetproducts(filter, argument, callback);
}
```

I want to the Getproducts function to be synchronous. What is the best way to achieve this like the following

```
void Getproducts(string filter, string augument, EventHandler<GetCompletedEventArgs> callback)
{
    _serviceclient.GetAsyncGetproducts(filter, argument, callback);
    //wait until callback comes back and return
}
```

EDIT: The proxy is providing any synchronous calls

Comment: Why don't you just use the synchronous method calls that the proxy generates for you?

Comment: The proxy is not generating synchronous calls

Comment: Do you control the generation of the proxy? Using svcutil.exe or using Visual Studio's Web Reference generation, synchronous calls are the default. It is much easier to just use this rather than wrap async calls.

Comment: We need both sync and async calls to exist for the same operation

Comment: @RoyDictus Well, it's not *that* hard, and it's always easier to make an async operation synchronous than a synchronous one asynchronous.

Comment: So you can let Visual Studio or svcutil.exe generate both synchronous and asynchronous method calls... See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: @carlosfigueira, Silverlight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot make synchronous networking requests in Silverlight** from the UI thread. There's no going around that. Even if you try to trick the asynchronous methods into behaving synchronously, it will not work. That's because if that were possible, the UI thread would be blocked, and the application would appear to be frozen. This happens because the responses to networking requests in SL are always delivered to the UI thread; if you wait for it on the UI thread itself, then you create a deadlock.

You essentially have two options: the preferred one is to actually go the asynchronous route. It's hard at first, if you're only used to synchronous programming, but it's a very valuable skill to have. The other option is to make the call on a background thread. I've tried it and it works, and some people have [blogged about it](http://weblogs.asp.net/razan/archive/2010/01/14/emulating-synchronous-web-service-call-in-silverlight.aspx), so you can try it as well. But AFAIK it's not officially supported.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just passing the callback parameter as the callback you'll want to assign your own callback that executes that method in addition to doing something else.  You effectively just need to trigger an event of some sort.  I have demonstrated one way using tasks, but you could just as easily use an auto reset event or one of any number of other synchronization methods.

```
void Getproducts(string filter, string augument, EventHandler<GetCompletedEventArgs> callback)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    _serviceclient.GetAsyncGetproducts(filter, argument, args =>
    {
        callback(args);
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    });

    tcs.Task.Wait();
}
```

Comment: I understand your idea. I tried your solution.But, the control is not going to the callback function and the application freezes foreever

Comment: +1, I was not upfront about the silverlight client. Nevertheless, good information from the answer.